# DocumentDB TransientFaultHandling for Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate my code to Core.

I was using DocumentDB TransientFaultHandling package, but I can't seem to find it for a Core library.

Is it still best practice to use it, or are there other options for achieving the same results?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current SDK (both Core and Full Framework) already include the fault handling that was part of the TransientFaultHandling package, not entirely the same since you can't define an exponential logic, but it works on the most common scenarios.

It's on the [ConnectionPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Mt733184.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions) settings:

```
var _dbClient = new DocumentClient("Db_uri", "Db_key", new ConnectionPolicy()
{
    MaxConnectionLimit=100,
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
    RetryOptions = new RetryOptions() { MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=3, MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=60 }
});
```

Comment: hmm... i kinda want the exponential logic back... :|

Comment: The APIs already return a header that says how many milliseconds you should wait, and the SDK reads and uses that. Which would be the benefits of an exponential backoff when you have the required wait time already being defined?

Comment: Based on the docs and the exposed properties this only appears to handle Throttling errors, not transient faults. I do not see anywhere that it indicates transient faults are handled by the SDK.

Comment: Transient faults (like 404s due to collection recreation for example) are also handled by the SDK. You can always use your own retrying library on top of the SDK, like Polly, if you want.